# Apache configuration for AngularJS with html5Mode enabled accessing PHP REST api outside DocumentRoot, how to?

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, rest

I have the following httpd structure:

```
c:/
  xampp/
    htdocs/
      mysite/
        bower_components/
        app/
          index.html
          app.js
          views/
        api/
          index.php
          .htaccess
```

Inside the `app` folder I have my application code: HTMLs, JSs, CSSs, etc. In other words my frontend.

Inside the `api` folder I have my PHP REST api: `index.php`. In other words my backend.

As said I am using `AngularJS` and would like to enable `html5Mode`, so I can have a cleaner URL.

I manage to put just the frontend to work with the following configuration in Apache:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8081

<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName localhost:8081
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/app"

    Alias "/bower_components" "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/bower_components"

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/app">
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With the configuration above I am able to run my frontend like a charm.
`http://localhost:8081` takes me to `index.html` and all my states in my `$stateProvider` are also resolved.

But my API calls fail and I don't know what to do.

I have the following REST service in my `index.php`:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Create Router instance
$router = new \Bramus\Router\Router();

$router->get('/cart/items', function() {
    echo '{"items":[ {"name":"item1"}, {"name":"item2"} ]}';
});

// Run the Router
$router->run();
```

When I call from my frontend:

```
$http({
    url: '/api/cart/items',
    method: 'GET'
}).then(function (response) {
    // do stuff...
}, function (error) {
    alert(error.data);
});
```

The call is falling in the rewrite rule to index.html. All my API calls are responding the index.html.

In my api folder I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

Options -Indexes
```

I have already tried to put an `Alias` in the Apache configuration for the `api` folder but the result was the same.

I've even tried to point my `DocumentRoot` to `C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite`. That way my calls to the API are resolved but when I access `http://localhost:8081` I get the list of files and folders from `mysite`.

It seems so close and yet so far. Hope you guys can enlight me.

Comment: Why not add <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/ then using .htaccess redirect properly to api or app? Even now vhosts file almost duplicates htaccess file

Comment: @jskidie Could you put an example on how to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure 100%.. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api/index.php?$1 [QSA, L] 
if there exists src in app folder:
RewriteRule src/(.*)$ app/src/$1 [QSA, L]

Comment: @jskidie I'll try that. I've edited the httpd structure to give a better overview of the scenario. You've mentioned about adding a directory, how would my vhost look like then?

Comment: No, edit existing <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/app"> to <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite">